# How do you identify the acknowledgements of certain TCP segments using Wireshark?

Tags: networking, tcp

Have a homework question I am confused by:

> When is the receiver ACKing every other segment it receives? Find an
>   example where the segment is not acknowledged while the segments
>   immediately before and after it are.

We are given a capture file of uploading a text file to a website. I'm just not sure how to identify if a segment has been ACK'd or not. All of the segments are listed as [ACK] so doesn't this mean they are all acknowledged? I also tried comparing the 'Acknowledgement Number' or the segments but I'm not sure how this helps me answer the question.

Comment: When the ACK flag is set, the segment is acknowledging everything prior to the acknowledgement number. The acknowledgement number is the number of the next expected data.

Comment: The question is poorly worded.  What I think it is asking about is when does the receiver *send* an ACK.  Since you are uploading a file, the sender will be sending many segments with a payload.   The receiver, however, probably isn't sending any payload back, but it is periodically sending back an ACK.  Does it immediately do so after receiving every segment (hint: no)?  When does it do so?